# Is the geometric formulation of Hamiltonian mechanics really necessary?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the symplectic manifold version of Hamiltonian mechanics used in Newtonian mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8256/why-is-the-symplectic-manifold-version-of-hamiltonian-mechanics-used-in-newtonia)

I was sitting around with some friends the other day trying to come up with an example of where the global formulation of Hamilton's Equations is really necessary.

Recall the formulation:
Given (M,omega,H) where

- M is a 2n dimensional real manifold
- omega is a symplectic form (closed non-degenerate two form)
- H: M -> RR is a Hamiltonian

Then one finds the Hamiltonian vector field X_H by solving omega(-,X_H) = dH and derives Hamilton's equations by saying that a Hamiltonian flow goes along this vector field.

What is a physical example where this formulation of Hamiltonian Mechanics is really necessary? Did Arnold (or whoever invented this) have some application in mind?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8256/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32095/2451